# Using SQL, what is the best practice for designing tables that behave like interfaces for other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to figure out what the best practices are for a situation I've encountered a few times over the past year.

To illustrate I've designed a fake database comprised of users, movies, and movies watched by users.

[image]

In this example, we want to be able to capture meta-data about any time a user watches a movie, like their location or the device they used, but the types of meta-data we may want to collect in the future may grow. The goal is to design a database that can aggregate many types of meta data for one movie watching experience.

So, I made a table called MovieWatchedMetaData to act like a bridge between different tables that contain meta-data. The premise is that this table will link the primary key from a meta data table like LocationWatched to a particular movie watching occasion.

I'm unsure about this approach and if it will be detrimental in the long run. Is this a poor practice? Is there a better, more appropriate way to accomplish this? How would you organize these tables?

Comment: The fact that `foreign_key_id` cannot be enforced, let alone made sense of which table it should reference, should be an indicator this is not a good idea.

Comment: True, that's definitely a red flag. I guess the alternative I'd go for is to include location_id and device_type_id in the MoviesWatched table.

Comment: [_Best practice for many:many_](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/4857/many-to-many-mapping-table).

Answer (score 1):

This was too long for a comment, so I'm making an answer instead. I'm typing on the run right now, but if I get time tonight I'll come back to this and give you an ERD to make more sense of it.

An interface to a table or set of tables should almost always just be a view. That being said, I see a few options:

1. Create a master metadata table with a movie occasion id and then an id for every type of metadata you want to link to  it. You can keep those other types of metadata in their own tables as you currently do. When you want to track additional data you need to add a column to the master metadata tracker table.
2. Look into your metadata simply being key/value pairs linked to a movie occasion and just having a view to pivot that table so the keys become columns and the values become rows in those columns. That gives you a dynamic interface to a movie experience with arbitrary metadata as long as you don't mind updating your view to accommodate extra columns when you want to add different types of metadata to track. If you don't mind retrieving your results in a procedure instead of a view, you can actually use dynamic sql to determine what metadata columns should be present based on the key/value pairs for the selected movie occurrences and build/execute your pivot query on the fly instead of having to recompile a view when you want a column added.
3. Why do you need to have each piece of metadata as its own column? If you can derive a generic structure for your metadata (maybe a name, description, nullable timestamp, value, and movie experience id), then you essentially end up with a bunch of metadata rows linking to each movie experience, kind of like you would imagine a blog post might have several tags linking to it except in our case a tag is actually an object with multiple fields.

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful response. I like the idea of using views to aggregate the meta-data I need. I may just use that suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What you have to consider is the "grunt" factor of adding a new aspect to the viewing data and the "grunt" factor of getting the data back out. There is no one solution (that I know of) that will fix it so you never have to modify your queries. (Though, consider exploring OO SQL expressions in PostgreSQL.)

1. It can be added as a field in VIEWING (which is your MoviesWatched table). For example, the viewing start time might fit nicely in the Viewing table. This would be for things that are unlikely to change structure.
2. It can be added as a table with a foreign key to viewing. For example, the ViewingLocation table has a set of coordinates. This has a 1:1 relation to Viewing and arguably *could* go in the Viewing table. But, today you might record them as GPS coordinates. Tomorrow you might want to add elevation or a link to a country.
3. It can be added as a link to a standard list of items, as I did for Device. Device might just list a simple, generic device and all the info you want to track about that device. A many-to-many join then connects it to the viewing as the DeviceUsage (or DeviceUsed) for the viewing. This would be for standard things that you want to reference over and over.

Notice that Viewer and Movie are really meta-data for the Viewing also. They're just a special case in that there is always only one of each. (What if you want to record more than one viewer per viewing. In the diagram I have, a Viewing is an event during which one person watches one movie. Two people watching the same movie at the same time would be two Viewings.)

So, I would probably create a database view that hangs everything off a viewing in order to retrieve and aggregate any meta data. I would add future meta data to each viewing depending on how it fits in one of the 3 criteria above. I would modify my database view as new meta data is added.

As my mentor once said, "That's one way."  I suspect this way has problems depending on the environment. I fully expect to be flamed. :-)  Would love to see other solutions--especially from someone familiar with OO-SQL.

Comment: I like your solution and actually ended up refactoring a model I've been working on to look more like yours. I think they main takeaway is what Uueerdo said in his initial comment - having a foreign key that can't be enforced is a bad idea, so having the viewing_id as a foreign key in my meta data tables is crucial. Thanks for the input!